# How to make SPARQL queries faster on Virtuoso by controlling query execution order?

Tags: sparql, freebase, virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I have set up a Virtuoso server for hosting Freebase data ([version 07.20.3217, built Jan  5 2017](http://202.120.38.146:8999/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=SELECT%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_dbms_name%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fname%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_dbms_ver%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fversion%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_build_thread_model%27%29%20AS%20%3Fthread%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_build_opsys_id%27%29%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fopsys%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_build_date%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fdate%20%29%0D%0A%23%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_lic_owner%27%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Fowner%20%29%0D%0A%23%20%28%20bif%3Asys_stat%28%27st_lic_serial_number%27%29%20%20AS%20%3Fserial%20%29%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%20%20%3Fs%20%20%3Fp%20%20%3Fo%20%20%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%201&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on); I really appreciate if [you can have a try](http://202.120.38.146:8999/sparql)).

Let's consider this scenario: find the largest location (probably a county, denoted by `?var1`) in Wisconsin State (`fb:m.0824r`), where `?var1` contains at least one location (denoted by `?var2`) with the type `fb:place_with_neighborhoods`.

I wrote the SPARQL query as follows:

```
PREFIX fb: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?var1 ?var2 ?v2_name WHERE {
             fb:m.0824r  fb:location.location.contains  ?var1 . 
             ?var1       fb:location.location.contains  ?var2 . 
             ?var2       fb:type.object.type            fb:location.place_with_neighborhoods . 
             ?var1       fb:location.location.area      ?area .
  OPTIONAL { ?var2       fb:type.object.name            ?v2_name } .
} ORDER BY DESC(?area) 
LIMIT 1
```

Unfortunately, the Virtuoso engine fail to return the query result for more than one hour.

I tried some simpler queries, which could produce results in less than one second:

```
PREFIX fb: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?var1 ?var2 ?v2_name WHERE {
             fb:m.0824r  fb:location.location.contains  ?var1 . 
             ?var1       fb:location.location.contains  ?var2 . 
             ?var2       fb:type.object.type            fb:location.place_with_neighborhoods . 
  OPTIONAL { ?var2       fb:type.object.name            ?v2_name } .    
}
# Remove the area-related information with ?var1
# Returns ONLY ONE result in 0.05s.
```

and,

```
PREFIX fb: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?var1 ?var2 ?v2_name ?area WHERE {
             fb:m.0824r  fb:location.location.contains  ?var1 . 
             ?var1       fb:location.location.contains  ?var2 . 
             ?var1       fb:location.location.area      ?area .
  OPTIONAL { ?var2       fb:type.object.name            ?v2_name } .
}
# Remove the type limitation of ?var2
# Returns ~7000 results in ~1s.
```

Given the results of those simpler queries, I'm really confused which step brought the performance issue. Is there anybody who can give me some advice? Thank you so much!

Comment: The result will be empty as there is no relation `fb:location.location.area` for the single result returned when removing the triple pattern with this property. The only property for `http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.05_jhl` is the `fb:location.location.contains` property.

Comment: Remove `OPTIONAL`, enable `&explain=on`.

Comment: @AKSW Yes you are right, I never found this point!So the problem becomes more interesting: how could virtuoso just hang there for so much time, while the query apparently should return empty ?

Comment: @StanislavKralin Awesome! The query works after the removal, and I'm really curious why. And where can I set "&explain=on" ?

Comment: @KangqiLuo, in general, `OPTIONAL` is slow. As to `explain`, perhaps this option is DBpedia specific, but one can call the `explain()` function somewhere in console.

Comment: Yes, OPTIONAL is basically a left-join. In general, query optimization can be a hard task, sometimes it helps to reorder the triple patterns (only the ones that are commutative). Some triple stores also do have some `hint` features, not sure if Virtuoso has something similar. But, you should ask on the mailing list or open a Github issue. The dataset seems to be small, especially the intermediate results. Maybe they could use your example to improve the query optimizer.

Comment: You can see how to analyze the query [here](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning#Erroneous%20Cost%20Estimates%20and%20Explicit%20Join%20Order) But to be honest, it's pretty hard to understand for non-experiences user resp. developer. But you could attach the output in your mailing list thread or Github issue then

Answer (score 2):

As noted on the [issue you raised on the project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/711) --

> There appears to be a query plan issue with `OPTIONAL` when the rest of the query produces no solution, as removing only that clause from your initial query [brings results near instantly](http://202.120.38.146:8999/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX+fb%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Frdf.freebase.com%2Fns%2F%3E+%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fvar1+%0D%0A++++++++++++++++%3Fvar2+%0D%0A++++++++++++++%23+%3Fv2_name+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++++++++++fb%3Am.0824r++fb%3Alocation.location.contains++%3Fvar1+.+%0D%0A++++++++++++++%3Fvar1+++++++fb%3Alocation.location.contains++%3Fvar2+.+%0D%0A++++++++++++++%3Fvar2+++++++fb%3Atype.object.type++++++++++++fb%3Alocation.place_with_neighborhoods+.+%0D%0A++++++++++++++%3Fvar1+++++++fb%3Alocation.location.area++++++%3Farea+.%0D%0A%23++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fvar2+++++++fb%3Atype.object.name++++++++++++%3Fv2_name+%7D+.%0D%0A%7D+ORDER+BY+DESC%28%3Farea%29+LIMIT+1%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on).
>
> Removing the `?var1 fb:location.location.area ?area` pattern (and therefore, the `ORDER BY DESC(?area)`), which is what reduces the solution set to zero, likewise [brings near instant results](http://202.120.38.146:8999/sparql?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX+fb%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Frdf.freebase.com%2Fns%2F%3E+%0D%0ASELECT+DISTINCT+%3Fvar1+%0D%0A++++++++++++++++%3Fvar2+%0D%0A+++++++++++++++%3Fv2_name+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++++++++++++++fb%3Am.0824r++fb%3Alocation.location.contains++%3Fvar1+.+%0D%0A++++++++++++++%3Fvar1+++++++fb%3Alocation.location.contains++%3Fvar2+.+%0D%0A++++++++++++++%3Fvar2+++++++fb%3Atype.object.type++++++++++++fb%3Alocation.place_with_neighborhoods+.+%0D%0A%23++++++++++++++%3Fvar1+++++++fb%3Alocation.location.area++++++%3Farea+.%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fvar2+++++++fb%3Atype.object.name++++++++++++%3Fv2_name+%7D+.%0D%0A%7D+%0D%0A%23+ORDER+BY+DESC%28%3Farea%29+%0D%0ALIMIT+1%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on).
>
> This issue will be raised with Development for their analysis.